# Is it OK to delete the content of a spam question?

Tags: support

<s>[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32476479/oracle-oaf-online-training)</s> (now deleted), that is clearly spam, recently appeared. It comes to my mind to replace its content with e.g.

> .......................................................

Is it OK to delete the content of a spam question? Or is just flagging it enough?

Comment: No it is not. It makes reviewing flags harder as well as makes it harder for others to judge the contents. Once a message is *handled* as spam (enough flags for auto delete or by mod intervention) the contents will be automagically be removed and the original content can be found in the revision history

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That happens automatically; for the benefit of users under 10k rep, here's what the question linked now looks like:

[image: deleted, spam-flagged question]

As pointed out in the comments, editing out the content yourself makes it harder for other users to review the post, and (especially if you're wrong in your assessment, although you clearly aren't in this case) could look like vandalism. Additionally, per the comments:

> it also has a significant danger of invalidating and/or rolling back flags. Which means it takes more reviews.

Long story short: **don't do it!**

Comment: great.... Copy that! :D

Comment: Well, it doesn't just make each individual reviewers job harder, it also has a significant danger of invalidating and/or rolling back flags. Which means it takes more reviews.

Comment: @Deduplicator good point, added